# Google Mobile Ad banner width on Android device display

Tags: android, admob, screen-size, banner-ads

I want to make use of Google AdMob banner in my Android Activity.

I have declared the AdView in my layout.xml to have a default size (ads:adSize="BANNER").

In documentation:
https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/intermediate#android
BANNER is declared to have a size of 320x50.

My device is HTC EVO 3D with size of 960x540.

AdView widget takes approximately 90% of screen width in portrait mode (540).

According to given sizes it should take approximately 50% of the screen.

What happens here ? Can someone explain it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size for the HTC EVO is 960*540 **pixels**.

The Admob banner is 320*50 **dip (density independent pixels)**. This is equivalent to the number of pixels that would be used on an mdpi device.

Since the HTC EVO is a hdpi device the banner will get scaled up to 150% of its size so to approximately 480*75 pixels.

You should be thinking and designing in **dpi** not pixels.